# Can I override the emulator and directly debug the app on my Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, sdk, emulation, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have my laptop that has a processor without Virtualization and Second Level Address Translation capabilities, that are required for running the new Windows Phone 8 SDK.

I can however use the Windows Phone 8 sdk, but for testing my apps I will use a windows phone 8 device.

Is it possible to not start the emulator and directly debug the app on my WP8 device?

Comment: According to me, I don't know how it could be possible. The emulator is integrated into the SDK, to test your app in a controlled environment. How can you debug your app directly on the phone, except installing and test it on the phone? I don't think Visual Studio has any library to work directly with any kind of WP8 phones. The only chances you have are: 1) Build the app, install it on the phone and test it. 2) Buy a new laptop, with the hardware requirements you need.

Comment: @AlbertoSolano Never heard of remote debugging? You should have a look, it's a precious tool when debugging an app on a remote server... Or a phone. Basically, it's just about running a lightweight debugger on the remote device, then Visual Studio communicates with it by TCP.

Comment: @KooKiz Never. Thanks for the advice. I'll check about it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio, on the drop down on the debug button (green play button) select "Device".

If the debug button is not visible, right click in the area with the toolbar(s)/menu bar and check "Standard".

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff928362%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_DeployingtoaPhysicalWindowsPhoneDevice)'s an article that talks about debugging windows phone apps on physical devices (at the bottom).